# не работает контролер angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

```js
   

   angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
   .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');

    function buildToggler(componentId) {
      return function() {
        $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
      };
    }
  });
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->  
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" style="height: 500px;" ng-cloak="" class="sidenavdemoCustomSidenav" ng-app="MyApp">

  <section layout="row" flex="">

    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-disable-backdrop="" md-whiteframe="4">

      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Disabled Backdrop</h1>
      </md-toolbar>

      <md-content layout-margin="">
        <p>
          This sidenav is not showing any backdrop, where users can click on it, to close the sidenav.
        </p>
        <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-accent">
          Close this Sidenav
        </md-button>
      </md-content>

    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">

      <div layout="column" layout-align="top center">
        <p>
          Developers can also disable the backdrop of the sidenav.<br>
          This will disable the functionality to click outside to close the sidenav.
        </p>

        <div>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-raised">
            Toggle Sidenav
          </md-button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </md-content>

  </section>

</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->
  
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->

  
</body>
</html>
```

пишет ошибку Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=AppCtrl не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: подозреваю, что нельзя апп в аппе делать, он ищет контроллер в `BlankApp`, и не находит

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev а как правильно

Comment: Уберите BlankApp везде)

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev убрал тогда такая ошибка

Comment: angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev изменения внес в вопрос

Comment: думаю это уже кто-то из этих не подключен - `'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'`, попробуйте без них запустить, потом подключайте по одному, чтобы понять с кем проблема. ps - еще не вижу где ваш js в html подключается, он должен быть после подключения всех зависимостей

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75287/discussion-between-vadim-and-artem-gorlachev).

Comment: Совет на будущее: при поиске проблем имеет смысл использовать не минифицированную версию ангуляра, тогда сообщения об ошибках будут намного информативнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`material.svgAssetsCache` не подключен (возможно его не нужно подключать вообще):

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');

    function buildToggler(componentId) {
      return function() {
        $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
      };
    }
  });
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-cloak ng-app="MyApp">
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" style="height: 500px;" ng-cloak="" class="sidenavdemoCustomSidenav">

    <section layout="row" flex="">

      <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-disable-backdrop="" md-whiteframe="4">

        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
          <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Disabled Backdrop</h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-content layout-margin="">
          <p>
            This sidenav is not showing any backdrop, where users can click on it, to close the sidenav.
          </p>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-accent">
            Close this Sidenav
          </md-button>
        </md-content>

      </md-sidenav>

      <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">

        <div layout="column" layout-align="top center">
          <p>
            Developers can also disable the backdrop of the sidenav.<br> This will disable the functionality to click outside to close the sidenav.
          </p>

          <div>
            <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-raised">
              Toggle Sidenav
            </md-button>
          </div>

        </div>

      </md-content>

    </section>

  </div>

  <!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->


</body>

</html>
```